# How to add Additive Regression (For multivariate data) in Neural Prophet Like in Prophet

Tags: time, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

How to add Additive Regression (For multivariate data) in Neural Prophet Like in Prophet.

i am working on data in which prediction is based on multiple Variables i want to integrate them with neural prophet.

Comment: For NeuralProphet, there are referred to as 'lagged regressors', here is the guideline link: https://neuralprophet.com/html/lagged-regressors.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer to this, or you already figured it out. I am starting to use Neural Prophet for the same thing, and I was able to add regressors like I do in Prophet, although the process is a bit different.

Not sure if you have the future values of the variables you want to integrate. If you don't, you should use 'm.add_lagged_regressor('variable')'. In my case, I have those future values, so I use add_future_regressors:

```
m = NeuralProphet()
m.add_future_regressor('variable A')
m.add_future_regressor('variable B')
m.fit(df, freq='M')
future = m.make_future_dataframe(df, periods=n_per, regressors_df=df_fut)
fcst = m.predict(future)
```

df has the historical data, with the time in column 'ds', the data to project in column 'y', and the past values of the regressors in 'variable X' columns.

df_fut has the future values of those variables, along with the future periods in 'ds'

It works as expected. Not sure if this helps.